# Normal approximation of martingale difference

Tags: pr.probability, martingales

Apologies in advance if the question is not precise (or silly), I am not a probabilist by profession. I have the following question:

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a martingale difference sequence. Assume that there is some "regularity" (say, existence of moments etc.). Define
$$
V_N := \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{E} (X_n^2 | X_1, \dots, X_{n-1} ).
$$

Then there are results saying that
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} X_n \cdot \mathbf{1}(V_n \leq t)
$$
has the distribution of $W(t)$ (standard Wiener process at time t), as $t \to \infty$, up to small errors. (e.g. Strassen: Almost sure behavior of sums of independent random variables and martingales. 1967 Proc. Fifth Berkeley Sympos. Math. Statist. and Probability (Berkeley, Calif., 1965/66), Vol. II: Contributions to Probability Theory, Part 1, pp. 315-343 Univ. California Press).

However, this is not what I need, since (if I read it correctly) it's not clear from the statement that the Wiener process $W$ is in some suitable sense independent of $(V_n)_{n \geq 1}$. Can these two be assumed to be independent?

For me the philosophy here should be:
The distribution of $\sum_{n=1}^N X_n$ (for large $N$) is the same as that of
$$
V_N \cdot X,
$$
(up to small errors), where $X$ is a standard normal variable that is *independent* of $V_N$. Is that true? I think what I would like to have in the end is not $\sum_{n \geq 1} X_n \cdot \mathbf{1}(V_n \leq t) \sim W(t)$, but $\sum_{n = 1}^N X_n \sim W(V_N)$, with $W$ independent of $(V_N)_{N \geq 1}$. Does that make sense?